# How to use multiple pageblock in single form or page in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to use multiple page blocks in single page or form. I tried it but it's not working properly. When I'm having only one page block, it's working properly. 

Can anyone give any suggestion for this question

Comment: We need to show at your code!

Comment: you are going to need to a) post a screen shot and b) post the VF (relevant excerpts).

Comment: please add your code and any errors

Comment: Ganesh, please understand that it's quite hard to help you if your question is short and does not fully describe or illustrate the problem you are having. This is why they are asking for your code. When something is "not working properly" please describe why this is the case, and how else you had expected it to work. Or definitely include any error messages you are seeing on the page or in the debug logs. If your question includes the steps you've already done yourself to attempt tof fix your issue, it becomes a lot easier for us to help you, and answer you.

Comment: Thnaks @SamuelDeRycke , Here after ill ask the question clearly

Comment: That's fine Ganesh, it's always a bit getting used to a new site and community. Know that if an answer helped you, you can mark it as such. On the left of every answer you can upvote the answer (everywhere!) and if it's on your own question you can also click the (V) button just below the up/down vote buttons. This will mark the answer as the solution to your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Page Block 1">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 1-1">
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 1-2">
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Page Block 2">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 2-1">
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 2-2">
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amatorvitae ,I tried in this way now its working , thnaks a lot